# Redirect unauthenticated user to Mastodon login screen

Tags: mastodon

I'm setting up a non-federated Mastodon instance for an organization. It's invite-only with `LIMITED_FEDERATION_MODE=true`.

I've also set `DISALLOW_UNAUTHENTICATED_API_ACCESS=true` which redirects anonymous users to the login page when attempting to view user profiles or toots.

But non-members can still see the instance home page (/explore). I would like anonymous users to be redirected to the login page when attempting to view any page on the instance.

<strike>Is that possible?</strike> How can I do that?

*Also posted to: https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/discussions/24061*